# ASP.Net application getting slow over time

Tags: asp.net, performance, session-state

Our users of a legacy web application written in ASP.net 2.0 are experiencing slow down after using the application over some time (after 2 hours or so).
For example, clicking a button performing some calculation and updating an ajax updatepanel takes several seconds while it is almost instant when they just have logged in.

If they log off and log back on of the web application, it gets back to the normal speed again, every time they do. The slow down is for a particular user and not global. It can fast for an user and slow for the user next to him.

I've looked at the IIS server and there is plenty of free memory in it and the CPU is almost always below 10%.
There are only a dozen users using this web application at time so scalability shouldn't be an issue.

The only think I can think of being affected by log offs, is session state.
I've already looked ViewState too and it is "only" 18kb at the slowest which shouldn't be the bottleneck, especially since they are on the same gigabit LAN and not remote. It is not any smaller when the applications runs fast.
Looking at session state in the code, it isn't used much and no large objects are stored.
According to my tests, it didn't grow bigger than 10 items and 500 bytes after a few minutes.
Even if there was a leak, the server should be able to cope with it considering the amounts of memory it has (4GB but only using 300MB).

I've cleared temporary files and it didn't seem to make any significant difference.

Do you think these slowdowns could come from something else than Session State, keeping in mind logging off and back on gets the speed back to normal?
If not, is there any tool you would suggest to profile sessionstate or a setting in IIS I should try to change?

Comment: Have you been able to looking into the actual page size?  This could be simply a client side issue being page size becomes to large.  You should be able to do this using Chrome or IE with Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

what does the browser's memory use look like on the client machines when they experience the slowdown? It could be memory leaks in your javascript if you are using lots of ajax stuff and the browser's memory use continuously climbs.

Comment: That's what I thought too and they have plenty of free memory on the workstations too and browser mem usage didn't seem that big. Besides, only logging off and back on restores the original speed, without need to actually close and start a new instance of the browser.

Comment: the only way you are going to get to the bottom of it is to run something like selenium and monitor it.

Comment: I second evert, even if there is extra memory in the workstations the leaks might be affecting the performance

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your database? (I assume you're consuming some data with an ajax app)

If you don't close the connection in the Finally block, you can wind up with zombie database connections that slow the app down. I don't know if this is the root cause, but probably worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an AJAX heavy page & the user is staying on the same page (i.e. lots of postbacks to itself) then it's possible that it's just ViewState growing to large. and the slow down you're experiencing is due to PageSize.

I would try and recreate the experience locally & monitor the page size/traffic with something like Firebug/Fiddler. If it is a ViewState/page size issue you could look at moving ViewState to the server side

See these for more info on it.

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2006/12/09/Move-the-ViewState-to-Session-and-eliminate-page-bloat.aspx

Comment: They are indeed staying on the same page for several minutes. I've looked at ViewState already and it is about 18kb, which is the same size whether it is slow or not. 18kb on a LAN shouldn't be too terrible either. It is slow even when refreshing an update panel so it shouldn't trigger a whole page refresh, even if it was big, but just modify the DOM on the fly?

Comment: Did you run fiddler to monitor the requests/responses ? I'd check again all the same. Just because the __ViewState hidden field isn't being updated (it's outside the update panel) doesn't mean that the PartialPostback isn't receiveing a larger amount of data up and down the pipe. http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll try it tomorrow and comment back. Fiddler seems small enough to be installed on end-users machine to diagnose.